# Impute missing values

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I want to impute some data. I use the data *moss* from the package *mvoutlier*. The goal is to impute the values < 0.004 from the column Bi. Because the *moss* date are compositional data, I use methods from the package *robCompositions*. When I try to impute the values, I get an error.

Code:

```
    library(mvoutlier)
    library(robCompositions)
    data(moss)
    attach(moss)

    x <- moss[-c(1,2,3)] # copying the data from moss, withoud the first 3 variables into x
    x$Bi[Bi < 0.004] <- 0 # the values that are under 0.004 are replaced with 0
    res <- impRZilr(x,dl=c(0,0,0,0,0,0.004,rep(0,25)))
    |=======                                                               |  10%Error in !all.equal(x[!w], xOrig[!w]) : invalid argument type
```

Don't know how to handle this error

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem, but I don't have a solution. This works: `res <- impRZilr(x[,c(1:5,7:31)],dl=rep(0,30))`, so the problem has to do with the Bi column. I don't have a clue what though.

Comment: Try replacing `x$Bi[Bi < 0.004] <- 0` with `x$Bi[x$Bi < 0.004] <- 0`

Comment: @crmhaske I tried what you suggested, but doing that I won't have the column _Bi_ in the result variable, so it's helpless

Comment: @jlhoward your suggestion has no effect on the result

Comment: Ya, I wasn't attempting to offer a solution, merely to demonstrate since it works without that column the error is in Bi... and jlhoward found the solution for you.

Comment: Ya, I get the same error

Comment: Interesting, I cleared the environment and did it again and it didn't work as well. When I use x$Bi[Bi < 0.004] <- 0.004 instead of 0, it works, so it appears not to like 0 for some reason. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: The idea is to impute the values < 0.004 and the method impRZalr replaces the 0 so in order to impute the values, I must first set the < 0.004 equal to 0

@crmhaske thanks for trying helping me

Comment: Why don't you try without using attach? It's [not a great practise to use it](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml#attach).

Comment: @Paul From the error, I tried to run the body of `impRZilr` leaving aside this line (towards the end) `if (!all.equal(x[!w], xOrig[!w])) stop(...`. `all.equal` does not always output `T` or `F`, but can output a character like `"'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 780 in target"` (which is the case in this example); so negating (`!`) a character will give the error you get. By commenting out this `if`, I get no error but it still prints this `10%`.

Comment: @Paul PS: As a note, `xOrig` is the entered "x", `x` is the manipulated "x" inside `impRZilr`, and `w` is the indices where "x" entered is `NA`. (These are all defined inside `impRZilr`).

Comment: Please don't put your solution inline in the question - instead you should post a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(mvoutlier)
library(robCompositions)
data(moss)

x <- moss[-c(1,2,3)] #copying the data from moss, withoud the first 3 variables into x
### Before
head(x$Bi)
## [1] 0.002 0.039 0.012 0.033 0.002 0.052

# Impute below 0.004
x$Bi[x$Bi < 0.004] <- 0

## head(x$Bi)
## [1] 0.000 0.039 0.012 0.033 0.000 0.052

# Imputation
result <- impRZilr(x, dl = rep(0.004, nrow(x)))
res <- data.frame(result$x)

head(res$Bi)
## [1] 0.002515667 0.039000000 0.012000000 0.033000000 0.002836172 0.052000000
```

As you can see, the values that were 0 are replaced by the impRZilr function values.

**EDIT**

Here is a description of how to access the results as required in your comments.

```
# Imputation
# Use the verbose = TRUE option to see how the algorithm is iterating
result <- impRZilr(x, dl = rep(0.004, nrow(x)), verbose = TRUE)

### Results description
str(result)
# List of 7
# $ x       : num [1:598, 1:31] 0.016 0.073 0.032 0.118 0.038 ...
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ : NULL
# .. ..$ : chr [1:31] "Ag" "Al" "As" "B" ...
# $ criteria: num 0.0203
# $ iter    : num 4
# $ maxit   : num 10
# $ wind    : logi [1:598, 1:31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ : chr [1:598] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# .. ..$ : chr [1:31] "U" "Bi" "Th" "Tl" ...
# $ nComp   : int [1:4] 4 6 3 5
# $ method  : chr "pls"
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "replaced"

# Results data.frame with imputed ceros
res <- data.frame(result$x)

# Index of missing values
index_missing_wind <- data.frame(result$wind)

# Number of iterations
result$iter
# [1] 4

# Method used (you can change this)
result$method
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it stops at 30%. The description of the method _impRZilr_ says that the result should have this form


    Value:

  xOrig : Original data frame or matrix

   xImp : Imputed data

   wind : Index of the missing values in the data

   iter : Number of iterations

    eps : eps


but in the end I don't get this structure

Comment: I used str(), but it didn't had that structure

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote in an edit:

> I managed to solve the problem, this is what I did:
>
> ```
>    x <-moss[-c(1,2,3)]
>    x$Bi[Bi <- 0.004] <- NA
>    res <- impAll(x)
> ```
>
> and the object *res* contains the imputed matrix.

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)